# Grails controller: how render image from byte array

Tags: image, grails, arrays, httpbuilder

I have byte array byteImg but I want render in my controller jpeg from byte array:

```
    def getSelfie = new HTTPBuilder()
    getSelfie.request(fullSelfieUrl, GET, JSON) { req ->
        headers.'X-DreamFactory-Session-Token' = session_id
        headers.'X-DreamFactory-Application-Name' = 'checkReg'
        response.success = { resp, reader ->
            assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200
            println "Get response: ${resp.statusLine}"
            println "Content-Type: ${resp.headers.'Content-Type'}"
            resp = reader as grails.converters.JSON

            String str = resp.toString()
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str)
            selfieRend = jsonObject.getString("selfie")
            byteImg = selfieRend.getBytes()

            render byteImg
            return byteImg
        }
        response.'404' = {
            println 'Information not found'
        }
    }
```

how to do it? Thank you so much

Comment: is this code residing in a controller action?

Comment: yes, code in a controller action

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but as per [wiki](http://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/AsyncHTTPBuilder) this should work:

```
def getSelfie(){
  def http = new AsyncHTTPBuilder(
            poolSize : 4,
            uri : fullSelfieUrl,
            contentType : ContentType.JSON )

  def result = http.get() { resp, json -> json.selfie.bytes }

  while( !result.done ) Thread.sleep 1000

  def bytes = result.get()

  response.setHeader 'Content-disposition', "inline; filename=someName.jpg"
  response.setHeader 'Content-Type', 'image/jpg'
  response.outputStream.withStream{ it << bytes }
}
```